# determine maximum number of days in particular month

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

from razor view I'm sending selected month and year to the controller using jquery.

Inside controller I'm receiving those selected values and create datetime properties

```
public ActionResult Index(int year, int month)
{
    Date1 = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
    Date2 = new DateTime(year, month, 31);
    ...
}
```

Some months has 31 day, some 30 and feb. has 28 (inside leap year 29) days.

My question is:

How can I recognize those months and based on that set appropriate max month day inside `Date2` variable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the [`DaysInMonth` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on `DateTime`:

```
Date2 = new DateTime(year, month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month));
```

Answer (score 2):

You want `DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month)`